# Rough estimate of programme execution time

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-languages, coding-efficiency

How to get rough idea of time taken by a programme on normal pc So that based on input I can know if my algorithm is going to get TLE or not with given time limit (2 sec etc..)

Suppose I have to traverse a array of size 10^6,10^7,10^7 etc..

I think it will take 1 sec for traversal of 10^6 array..

if anyone can explain it clearly.

Comment: There so many variables that can affect that. "Array of size" and "traverse" are both very ambiguous too. What does the array store? Are you really just traversing the memory of the array? Or are you doing anything with it? What sort of optimization have you enabled? Are you using any special functions? E.g. clearing memory can be done more quickly than setting the bytes to specific values.

Comment: On Linux, see [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). Also read books like [*Introduction to algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) about [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). In general you need to profile and benchmark your code

Comment: A good way is to run the program on your normal pc and time it. Also known as "benchmarking".

Comment: I want a general normal i5 , i3 PC idea. Like in some competition we are given some program with time execution limit to 1~2 sec and after that deciding algorithm and its time complexity like n^2 , nlogn we can get idea to of time based on input number n if that algorithm is worth considering or we need to think another solution...so rough idea before program writing.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Instructions per cycle for the current processor then I would look at the assembly code and calculate the number of cycles required.

Once you have the number of cycles, multiply it with cycle time.

Comment: Modern CPUs are very complicated, and it's extremely difficult to count cycles because of the effects of multiple layers of cache, and pipelining.

Answer (score 0):

Several factors are needed to be considered to reach to any conclusion in this case.

Every machine/assembly instruction takes **one or more clock cycles** to complete.

After fetching the assembly code for your program, you can calculate the total time using following formula:

`Execution time = Total number of cycles * Clock cycle time = Instruction count * cycles per instruction * clock cycle time`.

In general, you cannot directly estimate the the total time to process an array of size 10^6 to be 1 second.

The time to execute a program may be dependent on the following factors:

1. **Processor:** To find the closest estimate, you can read the processor manual  to get the cycles per instruction for an instruction (as different instruction takes different number of cycles to retire) and use the above formula.
2. **The data/operand:** The size of the operand (in your case, the data in the array), has effect on latency.
3. **Caching:** The time required to access the data on the same cache line is same. Therefore, the total time is also dependent on the number of cache lines the CPU needs to access in total.
4. **Compiler Optimizations:** The modern compilers are very smart in optimising the code where read/write operations are not involved. In your case, you are just traversing the array and not performing any operations. Therefore, due to the optimisation, it may take much less than 1 second to traverse the array.

Comment: Pipelining makes cycle-counting very difficult. You say "cache lines" but in reality there are multiple different caches on a modern CPU. Your answer suggests that estimating time from assembly code is easy (if tedious) whereas in reality it's extremely difficult.

Comment: Correct sir. That is why I mentioned "closest estimate".